# Getting errors when installing packages

Tags: installation, package-management

Which ever package I try and install I seem to get the following error

```
installArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ... Preconfiguring
packages ... Preconfiguring packages ... Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libphonon4. (Reading database
...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading
database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database
... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading
database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database
... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading
database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ...
286403 files and directories currently installed.) Unpacking
libphonon4 (from
.../libphonon4_4%3a4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ... Selecting
previously unselected package phonon-backend-gstreamer. Unpacking
phonon-backend-gstreamer (from
.../phonon-backend-gstreamer_4%3a4.7.0really4.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb)
... Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.
Unpacking gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg (from
.../gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-1_amd64.deb) ... Selecting previously
unselected package phonon. Unpacking phonon (from
.../phonon_4%3a4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ... Selecting
previously unselected package minitube. Unpacking minitube (from
.../minitube_1.6-1_amd64.deb) ... Processing triggers for
hicolor-icon-theme ... Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index... Processing triggers
for desktop-file-utils ... Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ... Setting up icaclient (12.1.0) ...
dpkg: error processing icaclient (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Setting up
libphonon4 (4:4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu1) ... No apport report written
because MaxReports is reached already Setting up
phonon-backend-gstreamer (4:4.7.0really4.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ... Setting
up gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg (0.10.13-1) ... Setting up phonon
(4:4.7.0really4.6.0-0ubuntu1) ... Setting up minitube (1.6-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ... ldconfig deferred processing now
taking place Errors were encountered while processing:  icaclient
Error in function:  SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
an error code (1) Setting up icaclient (12.1.0) ... dpkg: error
processing icaclient (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

please help....

Comment: What do you mean whichever package? Because from the output, everything installed correctly except the icaclient package.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and type the following:

1. `sudo apt-get clean`
2. `sudo apt-get -f install`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Check if whatever you were installing (I'm guessing the Citrix client) is installed successfully. If not, try the following:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install icaclient`

Answer (score 0):

you can try
sudo apt-get remove icaclient
if you still are trying to install the icaclient then take a look at this: http://crazymadeagle.blogspot.com/2013/07/howto-install-citrix-client-on-ubuntu.html

Which describes the issue you had and also how he solved it and how he installed icaclient.